# convertRect: toView: returns double size and twice the distance from the origin

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, retina-display

I pass in an image view to an init method that needs the size of the image view. Then call convertRect:toView:

```
- (id) initWithImageView:(UIImageView*) imageView {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        CGRect imageViewFrame = [[imageView superview] convertRect: imageView.frame toView: self.view];
    }
}
```

Which was called with:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithImageView:imageView];
viewController.delegate = self;
[self.tabBarController presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

imageViewFrame is then

```
(origin = (x = 0, y = -120.22867049625003), size = (width = 750, height = 750))
```

the imageView has a frame of

```
frame = (0 -60.1143; 375 375);
```

and it's super view is has a frame of

```
frame = (0 0; 375 254.5);
```

Why would it be scaled up x2 ?

Further testing on iPhone 6 plus (3x) simulator makes imageViewFrame

```
(origin = (x = 0, y = -199.30952358000002), size = (width = 1242, height = 1242))
```

The first tests were done on iPhone 6 simulator (2x).
Why is convertRect:toView: working in pixels and not points?

Comment: What is you class that you pass the ImageView to? Is it UIScrollView or something like that?

Comment: Why ain't you using directly imageview's frame like: `CGRect imageViewFrame = imageView.frame;`

Comment: ps4 - its just a UIViewController sub class

Comment: Mrunal - because i don't know [imageView superview] is going to be at 0,0 all the time.

Comment: You should provide more code, it is difficult to say what the problem is now. Where did you call this init function? Can you show it?

Answer (score 2):

In your `-initWithImageView:`, your `self.view` has not been generated yet, you can try to cache the `imageView` temporary, and do the rect converting action in `-viewDidLoad` instead:

```
// If you don't user Interface Builder
- (void)loadView
{
   CGRect frame = <your_view_frame>;
   UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
   self.view = view;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  CGRect imageViewFrame = [[imageView superview] convertRect:imageView.frame toView:self.view];
  ...
}
```

---

#### Edit

As the doc said for `-convertRect:toView:`'s view param:

> The view that is the target of the conversion operation. If view is nil, this method instead converts to window base coordinates. Otherwise, both view and the receiver must belong to the same UIWindow object.

If you persist in doing in `-initWithImageView` method, declare a custom view iVar, alloc & init in your `-initWithImageView` method, then in `-loadView`, assign the iVar to `self.view`. And of course, the way you used to convert rect in `-initWithImageView` should be

```
CGRect frame = <your_view_frame>;
_iVarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
CGRect imageViewFrame = [[imageView superview] convertRect:imageView.frame
                                                    toView:_iVarView];
```

In `-loadView`:

```
- (void)loadView
{
   self.view = _iVarView;
}
```

But it's not recommend to do it in this way, I suggest you init UI in the right methods of view's life loop.

Comment: That's great but for this situation i need the size in init. Does convertRect:toView: fall back to pixels if the view isn't loaded? Is calling self.view as an argument for convertRect:toView: is not early enough for it to work with points?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a correct method:
SWIFT:

```
extension UIView {

    func convertRectCorrectly(rect: CGRect, toView view: UIView) -> CGRect {
        if UIScreen.mainScreen().scale == 1 {
            return self.convertRect(rect, toView: view)
        }
        else if self == view {
            return rect
        }
        else {
            var rectInParent = self.convertRect(rect, toView: self.superview)
            rectInParent.origin.x /= UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
            rectInParent.origin.y /= UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
            let superViewRect = self.superview!.convertRectCorrectly(self.superview!.frame, toView: view)
            rectInParent.origin.x += superViewRect.origin.x
            rectInParent.origin.y += superViewRect.origin.y
            return rectInParent
        }
    }
}
```